# NDK-Build only generates Armv5 so

Tags: android, build

I'm a pretty newby when it comes to the android NDK, so here is my problem.

Whenever I build my native code, i only get arm v5 code, not v7, thats really my problem. My Android.mk file looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a

LOCAL_MODULE    := SignalProcessing
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := fir.c fourier.c fastmath.c   

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

As you can see, i have 3 native c files in there, when ever i run the ndk-build command, only 1 file appears in: libs/armeabi/libSignalProccsing.so. This is just the Armv5 file, where is the Armv7 file?

I've googled my ass off on this matter and can't find anything about it. The only info i can find is to ajust APP_ABI values, but ive tried that 10000 times. Ive even filled in nonsense values and i dont get an error on that, please help!

Regards,
Maarten

Comment: I use my self-developed [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) to bypass all that nonsense :)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really solve my problem (i already found my problem btw). I also don't want to write C++ code per se, i just want to use the NDK to speed up code since native code can be at least 2 times faster then java code plus I'd liek to stick to the standard Android API's and SDK's since there is alot of support for it and I'm not really a Linux/programming guru who knows how to handle all the 10000 files that come with the NDK and use them to use a different system to get thigns done.

Comment: I found my answer. I need to put the line 

    APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a

In Application.mk NOT in Android.mk.

Comment: JavaCPP relies on the standard Android NDK... it's just easier to use. I developed it for all the reasons you mention above.

Comment: I didn't really understand what all that is on your page, so ill just stick to the standard NDK, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. I need to put the line

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

In Application.mk NOT in Android.mk